# Node.js - spawned exe gives no output

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I am still learning C++ and just getting started with node, I created an IRC client in C++ for receiving messages in a chat, I wanted to then fetch these from Node.js by using the stream stdout from the spawned child process.

However I receive no output from the exe.
The only time I receive an output from the exe in the Node.js script is once I end the forever loop (irc_run), however I thought this would have no effect since it is spawned asynchronously?

The exe works fine when launched normally, it displays all messages sent.

Library used:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libircclient/

Consoleapplication1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "libircclient.h"
void event_numeric(irc_session_t *session, unsigned int event,
  const char *origin, const char **params,
  unsigned int count) {
  return;
}

void event_connect(irc_session_t *session, const char *event,
  const char *origin, const char **params,
  unsigned int count) {
  irc_cmd_join(session, "#username", 0);
}

void event_channel(irc_session_t *session, const char *event,
  const char *origin, const char **params,
  unsigned int count) {
  printf("%s\n", params[1]);
  irc_disconnect(session);
}
int main() {
  printf("Connected and setup.\n");
  irc_callbacks_t callbacks;
  memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks));
  callbacks.event_connect = event_connect;
  callbacks.event_numeric = event_numeric;
  callbacks.event_channel = event_channel;
  irc_session_t *session = irc_create_session(&callbacks);
  if (irc_connect(session, "irc.twitch.tv", 6667,
    "password", "username",
    "username", "username")) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (irc_run(session)) {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Debug.js:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var irc = spawn('C:/irc/ConsoleApplication1.exe');

irc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(String(data));
});
irc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(String(data));
});
irc.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: So, why not just use one of the myriad of irc modules for node.js and just forgo the C++ and child processes altogether?

Comment: Do you get "Connected and setup." message in your node process or you don't get anything at all?

Comment: This was mainly for a learning purpose, I am aware my approach is not the easiest way. :)
@kyrisu I do not receive the 'Connected and setup.' message, I do not receive anything at all.

Comment: @Linus for me your Debug.js is working fine with a sample C++ app (https://gist.github.com/kyrisu/fd01d375e8a145a517b0). Can you run my code and tell me if it works as expected? I'm suspecting that VisualStudio may somehow cause this (I'm on Linux so cannot check it at the moment).

Comment: @kyrisu It does indeed work as intended, no issues with that sample.